# Kernel compilation from source frozen at update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.7.1

Tags: linux

I've been trying to compile the Linux kernel v4.7.1 from source, and this is the farthest I've gotten so far. How do I complete the compilation succesfully?

The following are the last few lines that are on the console, before the cpu's usage hits 1%, so I'm assuming the compilation has frozen here.

```
  INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko
  INSTALL sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-us122l.ko
  INSTALL sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-usx2y.ko
  INSTALL virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
  DEPMOD  4.7.1

sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.7.1 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.7.1 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.1
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.7.1 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.1
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.7.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add:

`ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sda` in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf